# Откуда ajax берёт данные (фото, текст, заголовки и тд), после нажатия на кнопку, после чего показывает ещё контент?

Tags: html, css, ajax, база-данных

Ссылку на сайт не буду кидать (вдруг бздюлей дадут)...

- При открытии сайта показывается к примеру 10 карточек в каждой из которых находится - заголовок, текст, фото, кнопка, цена.
- Под ними находится кнопка "Показать ещё", при нажатии на неё показывается ещё карточек 10 и так можно нажать раз 5 - в итоге 50 карточек при нажатии на кнопку.

Вопрос 1: все эти данные (заголовок, текст, фото, кнопка, цена) берутся из БД?

Вопрос 2: если будет просто 10 картинок и при нажатии на кнопку, будут подгружаться ещё 50 штук, то откуда берутся фото кроме БД?

Answer (score 1):

**Вопрос 1: все эти данные (заголовок, текст, фото, кнопка, цена) берутся из БД?** - в целом это что угодно. Это может быть просто код который генерирует данные.

**Вопрос 2: если будет просто 10 картинок и при нажатии на кнопку, будут подгружаться ещё 50 штук, то откуда берутся фото кроме БД?** - по тому же принципу что и первый. Если это запрос к серверу то его обработка это его проблемы. Может сгенерировать, может считать из облака, из бд из файловой системы.

Comment: А вот если у меня заказ к примеру и мне дали макет. Так кнопка "показать ещё" при нажатии на которую подгружаются те же 50 картинок. Это получается нужно согласовывать с заказчиком где будут храниться фото (облако, бд и тд)?

И ещё одно - ajax же это уже по сути бэкенд?

Comment: Задачу пожалуйста сформулируйте. Что вам дали какой макет и что хотят?

Comment: Поймите заказ типа "хочу сайт чтоб заработать бабла" скорее всего в результате окажется прямой противополжностью

Comment: Или хочу Фейсбук за 1000$. На деле будет потеря 10000.

Comment: "хочу сайт чтоб заработать бабла" - фу даже думать о таком! (испробовал на себе 3 года назад)
Я имею ввиду, что если на сайте должна быть подгрузка данных, то нужно я так понимаю согласовывать с заказчиком где будут храниться эти самые данные, будь то облако, бд и тд.

P.s.
Если опять не особо понятно, то я извиняюсь и отдаляюсь) Никогда никому и ничего не умел объяснять.

Comment: На самом деле с заказчиком обсуждается все досконально и утверждается план работ и бюджет. Все отклонения ведут к изменению плана и бюджета. План менять можно, но нужно не забывать о бюджете.

Comment: @markus ajax - это асинхронное обращение к серверу, без перезагрузки страницы, сервер, скорее всего, вам нужно будет ручками сделать. Или использовать готовые api, например firebase, у него есть firestore, чтобы работать с файлами

Comment: @markus Надо начинать с того, кто вы для заказчика. Если вас просят сделать только макет, то может вас наняли как верстильщика, а после вас там будет разработчик фронтэнда согласовывать с разработчиком бек-энда как что работает и делать это. Или вы считаетесь фронт-энд разработчиком, тогда заказчик должен дать вам описание API по которому вы должны подтягивать данные (но это уже точно называется не 'сделать макет') или описать иной способ. Ну либо заказчик считает что вы фулл-стак разработчик и сделаете для него и фронт и бек.